# How can I find the mean between two time range(POSIXct) in R?

Tags: r, time-series

My data is in the form

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 01:00:00 | 10 |
| 2017-01-01 01:30:00 | 12.25 |
| 2017-01-01 01:40:00 | 12.76 |
| 2017-01-01 02:10:00 | 17.57 |
| 2017-01-01 03:00:00 | 19.01 |
| 2017-01-01 03:08:00 | 14.41 |
| 2017-01-01 04:00:00 | 11.23 |

class:
Time - Posixct
Value - Numeric

Now, I would like to find the mean of Value column between the time range of 2017-01-01 01:00:00 and 2017-01-01 03:00:00 in R.
I have failed miserably to work on this time series data. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading library lubridate for the ymd_hms function

```
library(lubridate)

Time_Val_dataframe <- data.frame(Time=c("2017-01-01 01:00:00","2017-01-
01 01:30:00", "2017-01-01 01:40:00", "2017-01-01 02:10:00","2017-01-01 
03:00:00", "2017-01-01 03:08:00","2017-01-01 04:00:00"), Value=c(10, 
12.25, 12.76, 17.57, 19.01, 14.41, 11.23))
```

changing class of the Time from character to time

```
Time_Val_dataframe$Time <- ymd_hms(Time_Val_dataframe$Time) 


library(dplyr)


Time_Val_dataframe %>% 
filter(ymd_hms("2017-01-01 03:00:00") > Time & 
Time > ymd_hms("2017-01-01 01:00:00")) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Value))
```

mean: 14.19333

```
Time_Val_dataframe %>% 
filter(ymd_hms("2017-01-01 03:00:00") >= Time & 
Time >= ymd_hms("2017-01-01 01:00:00")) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Value))
```

mean: 14.318

```
Time_Val_dataframe %>% 
filter(ymd_hms("2017-01-01 03:00:00") > Time & 
Time >= ymd_hms("2017-01-01 01:00:00")) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Value))
```

mean: 13.145

```
Time_Val_dataframe %>% 
filter(ymd_hms("2017-01-01 03:00:00") >= Time & 
Time > ymd_hms("2017-01-01 01:00:00")) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Value))
```

mean: 15.3975

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(between(Time, as.POSIXct('2017-01-01 01:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2017-01-01 03:00:00'))) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Value))
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1483212600, 1483214400, 1483215000, 
1483216800, 1483219800, 1483220280, 1483223400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Value = c(10, 12.25, 12.76, 17.57, 19.01, 
14.41, 11.23)), .Names = c("Time", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Assuming that the input `DF` is as shown reproducibly in the Note below (and that if there were more than one day you want the mean over all days between the indicated times) then extract the times as character strings, perform the required subset and take the mean.    No packages are used.

```
tim <- sub(".* ", "", DF$Time)
mean(DF$Value[tim >= "01:00:00" & tim <= "03:00:00"])
## [1] 14.318
```

**1a)** The first line could alternately be:

```
tim <- format(DF$Time, "%H:%M:%S")
```

**2)** If there were several days and the mean for each day were wanted separately then:

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, Date = as.Date(Time), Time = sub(".* ", "", Time))
DF0 <- subset(DF2, Time >= "01:00:00" & Time <= "03:00:00")
aggregate(Value ~ Date, DF0, mean)
##         Date  Value
## 1 2017-01-01 14.318
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Time,Value
2017-01-01 01:00:00,10
2017-01-01 01:30:00,12.25
2017-01-01 01:40:00,12.76
2017-01-01 02:10:00,17.57
2017-01-01 03:00:00,19.01
2017-01-01 03:08:00,14.41
2017-01-01 04:00:00,11.23"
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
DF$Time <- as.POSIXct(DF$Time)
```